# Quartiles - what computation method is correct?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am not sure what method use for computation a lower and upper quartil. In my textbook there is a rule for lower quartil -"lower quartil is median of lower half of data" and "upper quartil is median of upper half of data". But when I compute these quartils in Open Office Calc the results are different.

For example I have this table of frequencies:

```
value   frequency
3       1
6       4
7       15
8       10
10      10
```

In my oppinion (and according to my textbook) the upper quartile is 9 and not 7,5 as is counted in OpenOffice Calc.

What value is correct?

Comment: 7.5 is the median. Are you sure you didn't have Calc compute that by mistake?

Comment: 7.5 is median but for Calc it's the upper quartile.

Comment: How exactly are you finding the upper quartile in Calc?